# Loading data issues

Tags: r, csv, upload, import-from-csv

Datalink:
[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt4l10nel5bwxoq/GTAP_ConsIndex.csv)

Code:

```
 ccfsisims <- read.csv(file = "F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/GTAP-CGE/GTAP_NewAggDatabase/NewFiles/GTAP_ConsIndex.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
 ccfsirsts <- as.data.frame(ccfsisims)
 ccfsirsts[7:25] <- sapply(ccfsirsts[7:25],as.numeric)
 ccfsirsts <- droplevels(ccfsirsts)
 ccfsirsts <- transform(ccfsirsts,sres=factor(sres,levels=unique(sres)))
 ccfsirsts[1:5,]
```

Issue:

So, if you check the column "pSVIPM", the values displayed in the dataframe "ccfsirsts" are different from what is actually saved in the .csv file. This problem occured when uploading a different set of data.

In the initial upload, i.e. "ccfsisims", everything seems to check out. It is afterward that the problem occurs.

Any thoughts on why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you load `ccfsisims` do `str(ccfsisims )`...(get in the habit of doing this)

you will see that `pSVIPM` is a factor. So `as.numeric` will simply change the factors to numbers in the order the levels appear.

Because if you look at your csv you have `#DIV/0!` characters in there.

try it yourself:

```
> length(ccfsisims$pSVIPM[ccfsisims$pSVIPM == "#DIV/0!"])
[1] 350
```

Comment: So, is the fix is to get rid of the "#DIV/0!" entries?

Comment: essentially yes, but are you not concerned by this problem with your data?

Comment: no, because i know the source of the problem. I compute ratio shares from simulation results for my variables which are reported in percent change in my model. For certain sims, there is no change observed in the variable, thus it report a zero percent change. I should have just put a conditional statement in my csv files while computing those shares to correct for it :)

But thanks for the piece of advice, I appreciate it.